# How to remove single quotes from a string, leaving only the words?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove single quotes from a string, but not quotes that are apostrophes.

For instance, I want to convert this:

```
"I'm a very 'dumb' stackoverflow user."
#=> I'm a very dumb stackoverflow user.
```

So something like `string.gsub("'", "")` 
won't work as it replaces all single quotes. The `'` in `"I'm` should not be replaced".

Comment: How would you handle `'I'm' a very dumb user`?

Comment: You mean the initial string is "I'm a very 'dumb' stackoverflow user.", correct?

Comment: No, the initial string is what I posted... I checked StackOverflow and it seems everyone wants to truncate leading/trailing double spaces, hence this new question.

Comment: What happens when you have a plural possessive, like "species' status"?

Comment: Can't think of a way to cover all cases and possible human errors. You may be finding yourself diving into language recognition algorithms to really be able to always sanitise this kind of texts correctly.

Comment: Yes, @theTinMan, and what about oddball endings that drop the final s for the sake of euphony, like "for conscience' sake" or "the phoenix' wings" ?

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. The situation and need isn't well defined, and naive solutions being asked for will mangle text in ways that will probably cause more problems downstream.

Answer (score 7):

You need to determine what uniquely represents a single quote. For example, it could be:

- a quote followed by a space
- a quote preceded by a space

In that case, you can use:

```
s = "I'm a very 'dumb' stackoverflow user."
s.gsub(/( '|' )/, ' ')
# => "I'm a very dumb stackoverflow user."
```

However, you must ensure that this condition is correct. If it's not, then you need to isolate (and enforce) another condition you can work on.

Comment: Thanks, I assume  s.gsub(/( '|' |^'|'$)/, ' ') would also work when the quotes are in the beginning/end of the sentence?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you may want to use `\A` and `\z` instead of `$` and `^`.

Comment: "Chris' car".gsub(/( '|' )/, ' ') #=> "Chris car".

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm perfectly aware of the possible issues, but as I mentioned there is no perfect solution. It depends on what constraints the user can set. It's even possible to enhance the regexp to only match opening/closing quotes, where the opening is space|beginning+char and closing is char+space|ending. But I'll leave that as exercise to the user. ;)

Comment: The solution is of limited value if it removes something as common as apostrophes used for possessives with words ending in "s". Also, many words begin with apostrophe's ("'twas"), with also would be removed. The OP has set the conditions precisely: the character `"'"` is to removed unless it serves as an apostrophe. Apostrophes are well-defined.

Comment: @CarySwoveland feel free to provide a better alternative then.

Answer (score 1):

Since you likely want to remove quotes and leave apostrophes intact, I would go with *proper utf-8 apostrophes*:

```
"I'm a very 'dumb' stackoverflow user.".gsub(/(?<=\p{L})'(?=\p{L})/, '’')
                                       .delete("'")
#⇒ "I’m a very dumb stackoverflow user."
```

What we use here is both positive lookbehind and lookahead: single quotes, having *a letter* on both sides around it, would be considered being apostrophes.

The other answer would leave a half of quotes in `"He said 'yes', though technically (say, 'literally') he did not want to."`

Comment: Switching to UTF-8 can cause problems downstream if the text is being rendered or stored in something that doesn't like UTF-8.

Comment: If in 2016 one is still developing smth that has glitches with utf-8, the problem is way deeper, that single quotes.

Comment: That may be, but in legacy systems we sometimes don't get a say about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. If this is a case, one might gsub them back to single quotes as the last step.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want apostrophes to be replaced(suppose that you're using ASCII), you can simply remove quotes having something non-letter beside them.

```
"I'm a very 'dumb' stackoverflow user.".gsub(/((?<!\w)'|'(?!\w))/, '')
```

You can't say for sure that a quote is a apostrophe. There is no accurate rule for detecting them. They can exist at end of a word like in "I took James' bag!". But the provided regex can detect them in most cases.

Comment: What happens with "species' status"?

Comment: It's not necessary, or desirable, to tell us you edited something. We can tell when and what was changed if we need to. Also, don't use "Edit" or "Update" tags to mark changes. Put the changed information into the text as if it was there initially. Again, we can see what changed if we care.

Answer (score 0):

You might restrict it to apostrophes surrounding a 'word':

```
"It's my 'dumb' species' status".gsub(/'([\S]+)'/, '\1')
 => "It's my dumb species' status"
```